# How to migrate or move activites between contacts in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-portals

Two different contacts had the same email address, after an automatic record creation rule was applied, CRM associated email activities to the wrong contact. I've updated the email address value in one of the contacts (the wrong contact)  but it has activities that do not belong to it and I need to move them to the right contact.

How can move activities between two contacts? I cannot merge the contacts as they are legitimate contacts.

I did try to update the partyid field of the activityparty entity but I've got the error message: The update method does not support entities of type 'activityparty'.

What easy way can I use to accomplish this?

Comment: If you can't update, it should be possible to create new emails on the right contact and delete the incorrect emails

Comment: How did you try to update the `partyid` field? If via code, can you show what you did?