# How to transfer Activities (mails, notes, etc) from one contact to another in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Due to some bad practices from one of our internal users. We need to transfer all activities (mails, notes, etc) from one contact to another contact. I was trying to achieve this via UI and I could not find a way to do this.

Is this possible? I'm looking for any way to achieve this, wether is CRMTool, SSIS, UI or any other way. Only admins will do this so we do not need anything fancy as it will be done maybe 4 times a year to clean up some data.

Thanks a lot :)

Tried using UI but no success.

Comment: Is this question same as this https://stackoverflow.com/q/58228462/7920473 ?

Comment: Looks like is the same question, but I didn't wrtie that question though.

Comment: What did you end up with?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to do these updates.

The first method is selecting a view on an activity where the owner is listed (i.e. All Phone Calls) and exporting to Excel. This downloads a XLSX with some hidden columns at the start where IDs for the records are kept. You then update the owner column with the new owner (take care of copying the exact fullname), and then importing the Excel spreadsheet again. You would need to repeat this export/import steps for each activity type (phone calls, email, etc.). So this might be impractical if you have a large volume of date, because of the need to repeat and because there are max numbers of records that you can export.

The other way to do this is using some .NET code. Of course, to do this you will need to use Visual Studio 2019.

If that's the case, this will do the trick:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;

namespace ChangeActivitiesOwner
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "AuthType=Office365;Url=<TODO:URL>;Username=<TODO:User>;Password=<TODO:Pass>;";
            string oldUserFullname = ""; // TODO: place here fullname for the user you want to overwrite
            string newUserFullname = ""; // TODO: place here fullname for the user you want to overwrite with

            CrmServiceClient client = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
            IOrganizationService service = client.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? client.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)client.OrganizationServiceProxy;

            QueryByAttribute qbyaOldUser = new QueryByAttribute("systemuser");
            qbyaOldUser.AddAttributeValue("fullname", oldUserFullname);
            Guid olduserid = (Guid)service.RetrieveMultiple(qbyaOldUser)[0].Attributes["systemuserid"];
            QueryByAttribute qbyaNewUser = new QueryByAttribute("systemuser");
            qbyaNewUser.AddAttributeValue("fullname", newUserFullname);
            Guid newuserid = (Guid)service.RetrieveMultiple(qbyaNewUser)[0].Attributes["systemuserid"];

            foreach (string activity in new string[]{ "task", "phonecall", "email", "fax", "appointment", "letter", "campaignresponse", "campaignactivity" }) // TODO: Add other activities as needed!!!
            {
                QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(activity)
                {
                    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("activityid", "ownerid")
                };
                query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("ownerid", ConditionOperator.Equal, olduserid));

                foreach (Entity e in service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities)
                {
                    e.Attributes["ownerid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", newuserid);
                    service.Update(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please complete the lines marked with "TODO" with your info.

You will need to add the packages Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies, Microsoft.CrmSdk.Deployment, Microsoft.CrmSdk.Workflow, Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDIrectory and Newtonsoft.Json to your solution, and use .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP is not talking about changing owner, but changing the recipients, attendees from one contact to another

Comment: It depends on the activity. For tasks, notes and others, the owner is the contact/person that the activity refers to. For phone calls, it depends on the direction of the call. From the OP description, it seems to me that it's referring to the owner because it mentions an internal user. In any case, let's wait for feedback from OP. The first option (export/import to XLSX) can be used in all cases, code can be modified to set other attributes, but it'll be longer.

Comment: Activity parties are not simple as that. Also completed activities cannot be edited without reopening it.

Comment: @ArunVinoth well, they can be edited without reopening if you do it from code. It's true you can't from the UI. Not sure about editing a closed activity using the export/import method, I'll check that on a trial and let you know.

Comment: I can confirm that you can also update a closed activity exporting and reimporting it. Apparently the read only state of the record are only from it's form. It also might be important that I tested using a System Administrator user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses Luc and @Arun.
Certainly, I don’t need to change the owner of those activities. I do need to change the recipients, attendees from one contact to another.
I did try exporting and exporting email activities to update the From and To fields, but I cannot update parties unless emails are in draft status. And if I change their status to draft, fields of type PartyList are not supported by the data import tool.

Comment: @luc What other way can I use to move activities from one contact to another?

Comment: @MANUELAN00 let me check if contacts can be changed from code for closed activities.